# W25q64 Nor flash does not get Erased

Tags: non-volatile-memory

I am trying to write the data into the NOR flash but for some reason it is taking some random/garbage data .
First i tried to erase the sector 
then i read the data from the same location which i have erased so i get some garbage data so it seems that it does not erase the data .below is the code called from main

```
uint8_t datatemp[128];

 W25QXX_erase_Sector(0);
 W25QXX_Read(datatemp,0 , 128);


void W25QXX_erase_Sector(uint32_t Dst_Addr)
{
    // Monitor flash erase, test
    printf("fe:%lx\r\n",Dst_Addr);
    Dst_Addr = Dst_Addr * 4096;
    W25QXX_Write_Enable(); //SET WEL
    W25QXX_Wait_Busy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4,GPIO_PIN_RESET); //Enable device
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte(W25q64_SectorErase); //Send sector erase instruction
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte((uint8_t)((Dst_Addr)>>16)); //Send 24bit address
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte((uint8_t)((Dst_Addr)>>8));
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte((uint8_t)Dst_Addr);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4,GPIO_PIN_SET); //Cancel the chip selection
    W25QXX_Wait_Busy(); //Wait for erasure completion
}

void W25QXX_Read(uint8_t* pBuffer, uint32_t ReadAddr, uint16_t NumByteToRead)
{
    uint16_t i;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4,GPIO_PIN_RESET); //Enable device
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte(W25q64_ReadData); //Send read command
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte((uint8_t)((ReadAddr)>>16)); //Send 24bit address A23-A16
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte((uint8_t)((ReadAddr)>>8)); //A15-A8
    SPI1_ReadWriteByte((uint8_t)ReadAddr); // A7-A0
    for(i = 0; i < NumByteToRead; i++)
    {
        pBuffer[i]=SPI1_ReadWriteByte(0xff); //cyclic reading- 0XFF
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_4,GPIO_PIN_SET); //Cancel the chip selection
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i am starting to write at 0th location so directly passing as 0 in erase sector function

Comment: I'm just talking about this line `Dst_Addr = Dst_Addr * 4096;`. Could you post the setup of your SPI? Does reading the menufacturer / device id work?

Comment: yes it work and its give me manufacture id = 0xEF, product id = 0x4017

Comment: hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)

Comment: hi , i am referring the code form the se link                                           https://github.com/SmartHW/Iov/blob/master/HARDWARE/W25QXX/w25qxx.c

Comment: Does write access work? If you write a register and read it back, does it hold the correct value?

Comment: hi , i am facing the issue in write ,as it does not work for me, as per the above link code first it erase the sector but when it start copying the data it hang out so i am not getting what is happening                                                                   W25QXX_erase_Sector (secpos); // erase this sector
   for(i=0;i<secremain;i++) //copy secremain
   {
    W25QXX_BUF[i+secoff] = pBuffer[i];
   }

Comment: hi waiting for your reply

Comment: Did you read the section about write protection in the datasheet? Can you read back the status register and check if the `write enable latch` is still set after the `W25QXX_Write_Enable()` command?

Comment: hi , i checked in the erase sector function after the W25QXX_Write_Enable();                                                     W25qxx_Spi(0x05);
status=W25qxx_Spi(0xFF);
w25qxx.StatusRegister1 = status; status = 0x7e that means WEL is enabled

Comment: And after the call of `W25QXX_erase_Sector()` it is 0 again? That would mean that writing in general works as expected.

Comment: Yes intially WEL is disable before the erase sector ,then after W25QXX_Write_Enable(); WEL is enabled (status = 0x7e),then after W25QXX_erase_Sector() it is WEL is disabled i.e status = 0x7c

Comment: Then you may have to clear the `BLOCK PROTECT BITS` before erase

Comment: hi i read the datasheet just want to confirm below is the correct way to do                     W25qxx_Spi(0x01);W25qxx_Spi(0x80);W25QXX_erase_Sector();

Comment: I'd say that should work, you can again confirm by reading back the status register before you send the actual erase command.

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: no its not working yet